# Saltstack Ext-Pillar get host IP from Netbox

Tags: salt-stack

I am looking to use a vairable in device1.sls to get the host value from Netbox.
I am able to do this from cli: `salt 'device1' pillar.get 'netbox:primary_ip4:address`

Can this be done from the .sls file and if so what is the syntax?
You can see the syntax I have tried below, but it does not work.

srv/pillar/top.sls

```
base:
  '*':
    - default
  device1:
     - device1
```

srv/pillar/device1.sls

```
proxy:
  driver: junos
  host: {{ salt['pillar.get']('netbox:primary_ip4:address') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "#!jinja|yaml" to the first line of srv/pillar.device1.sls as per https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/renderers/ to force the jinja to render.

Another approach would be to move this up in the salt states instead, so when you're looking up the proxy data, you could do something like below:

```
{% set my_proxy = {{ salt['pillar.get']('proxy') %}
{% set my_proxy_host = {{ salt['pillar.get']('netbox:primary_ip4:address') %}
```